# Minimize overlap in class schedule

Tags: optimization, scheduling

At our school, we have a schedule that looks like the following (simplified):
[image]

Remarks:

- One course can be taught multiple times a week (to different class-groups, like 1A, 1B and 2A)
- Multiple lessons (even from the same course) can be scheduled on the same time (but of course for different class-groups).

Some of our students need to take classes in different class-groups (for example: they take the courses Databases and Linux). In that case, we need to check if there is an overlap between the lessons of the different class-groups, but eliminating all overlap is not always possible.

Is there an algorithm that, given a set of courses a student should take, can minimize the number of overlapping lessons?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Scheduling is a normal task for maximum flow algorithms, however, in practice, it could be that off-the-shelf CSP solvers are both easier to use and better.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I've tried Google OR-tools, but I can't figure out how I should model this problem as a constraint satisfaction problem. Could you give me some pointers please?